# Haskell deleting in a binary search tree

Tags: haskell, binary-search-tree

So far I have come up with something like this. What I am trying to do here is get the right most or the leftmost element depending on which is available and swapping them with root and deleting the corresponding rightmost or left most element. I just need some help figuring out why it fails when I ask it to delete root of a tree but it works for all other cases and what does Irrefutable pattern failed mean?

If I do something like `delt 3 Node 3 (Node 2 (Node 1 Empty Empty) Empty) (Node 4 Empty Empty)` 
it gives an error like `Node *** Exception: delt.hs:26:40-75: Irrefutable pattern failed for pattern (Main.Node rm (Main.Empty) (Main.Empty))`

`delt 2 a` gives `Node 3 (Node 1 Empty Empty) (Node 4 Empty Empty)`

```
data Tree a = Empty | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) deriving (Show, Read, Eq)
treeIns :: (Ord a) => a -> Tree a -> Tree a
treeIns x Empty= Node x (Empty) (Empty)
treeIns x (Node a l r)
  | x == a = Node a l r
  | x < a = Node a (treeIns x l) r
  | x > a = Node a l (treeIns x r)

leftm :: Tree a -> Tree a
leftm Empty = Empty
leftm (Node a (Empty) (Empty)) = (Node a (Empty) (Empty))
leftm (Node a (l) (Empty)) = leftm l
leftm (Node a (l) (r)) = leftm l

rightm :: Tree a -> Tree a
rightm Empty = Empty
rightm (Node a (Empty) (Empty)) = (Node a (Empty) (Empty))
rightm (Node a (Empty) (r)) = rightm r
rightm (Node a (l) (r)) = rightm r


delt :: (Eq a, Ord a)=>a -> Tree a -> Tree a
delt x Empty = Empty
delt x (Node a (Empty)(Empty))
  | x== a = Empty
delt x (Node a l r)
  |x == a = (if l /= (Empty) then (let (Node rm (Empty) (Empty)) = rightm l in (Node rm (delt rm l) r)) else (let (Node rm (Empty) (Empty)) = l\
eftm r in (Node rm l (delt rm r)) ))
  |x>a = Node a (l) (delt x r)
  |x < a = Node a (delt x l ) r
```

Comment: I think there is a much simpler solution. Hint: 1) when deleting y from a tree (x, left, right), there's 3 cases where y might be: in root, in left, or in right. 2) introduce and use an "append :: Tree a -> Tree a -> Tree a" operation.

Comment: Irrefutable pattern errors are likely due to `let Node rm Empty Empty = rightm l in ...` when `rightm l` returns `Empty` or a node with non empty subtrees. Maybe you should use `case` instead to catch all the possibilities?

Comment: Style comment: parentheses near single identifiers like `(l),(Empty)` are always redundant. I'd suggest to remove them.

Comment: @chi Thanks. I'll try using case .  jkff I'm trying to figure out how I could use append for delete tree. As of now I'm not much comfortable with functional programming.

Comment: Deletion in a BST is a bit tricky, in my opinion (both in imperative and functional languages). If your goal is learning functional programming, maybe you could start with some easier task.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a similar implementation just for reference. (Without the delete part though)

```
-- a tree can be empty or contain a value with two other Trees
data Tree a = EmptyTree | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) deriving (Show, Read, Eq)

instance Functor Tree where
    fmap f EmptyTree = EmptyTree
    fmap f (Node x left right) = Node (f x) (fmap f left) (fmap f right)

-- create a Node with a value and two Empty subtrees (left and right)
singleton :: a -> Tree a
singleton x = Node x EmptyTree EmptyTree

-- insert a new Node into a tree
insertInTree :: (Ord a) => a -> Tree a -> Tree a

-- insert into empty tree is equal to creating a new tree
insertInTree x EmptyTree = singleton x

-- pattern match on value and subtrees
insertInTree x (Node a left right)
    -- if element is equal to root element, return same tree
    | x == a = Node x left right

    -- if element is smaller than root, go to left
    -- subtree and check again.
    | x < a = Node a (insertInTree x left) right

    -- if element is bigger than root, go to right
    -- subtree and check again.
    | x > a = Node a left (insertInTree x right)

-- binary tree search
search :: (Ord a) => a -> Tree a -> Bool

-- search in EmptyTree is always False
search x EmptyTree = False

-- serach in a Node
search x (Node a left right)

    -- if element equals root element, great
    | x == a = True

    -- if element is smaller than root, continue search on the left side
    | x < a = search x left

    -- if element is bigger than root, continue search on the right side
    | x > a = search x right

-- create a test tree
myTree = foldr insertInTree EmptyTree [15,75,651,2,3,4,85,42,1,5,36,45,78,12,2]
```